# Shortest sentence with 2 sets of synonyms?

Tags: open-ended, language, english

**Current Best: *13 characters***

This time I'm asking you guys to determine *the shortest possible grammatically correct english sentence* that includes **2 pairs of synonyms** (different words that mean the same). For checking character count you can use the site http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/charcount.shtml

To determine if a word is a synonym, it either has to be obvious, or has to be confirmed by thesaurus.com.

**The accepted answer will always be changed to adjust to the shortest answer which follows all the rules. So any answer can be *bested* at any point by another solver!**

Here's an example incase any of you are confused;

**Characters: 64**

> What a beautiful, giant flower! Almost as pretty as my big tree!

*Beautiful and Pretty; To look good.*
*Giant and Big; To be large in size.*

---

*Please note your answer will not be accepted if it ties the accepted answer!*

Comment: I assure you (especially @xnor) the rules will stay constant. As it's not as hard to make a sentence like this

Comment: 'Not as hard' - indeed, almost too easy IMO.

Comment: Now down to 13...

Comment: Oi warspy, how come you accept 'go' and 'via' as synonyms but not 'be' and 'am'? :-)

Comment: I've VTCed this question as 'primarily opinion-based'. It doesn't *look* like it is, but this is how the OP is judging answers (see [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/trick-or-treat-probability-puzzle/6339?noredirect=1#comment20620_6339)).

Comment: @rand al'thor I think I'm gonna delete it anyway, look at the the DVs

Comment: @rand al'thor I actually cannot delete it. I guess I'll have to reactor your answer rand. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I can't undo my VTC though :-(

Comment: @rand al'thor Why not? Close -> Retract Close Vote

Comment: OK, I'd forgotten that was possible!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 15 Characters

> I gaze; see me!

*I and me: first person plural pronoun. Gaze and see: use one's visual sense.*

### 14 Characters

> I rise; up me!

*I and me: first person plural pronoun. Rise and up: increase or raise upwards.*

### 13 Characters

> An os, a gob.

*An and a: indefinite article. [Os](http://www.scrabblefinder.com/word/os/) and [gob](http://www.scrabblefinder.com/word/gob/): mouth.

Comment: One can 'up' one's prices, but can a person be 'upped'? I think so, at least colloquially.

Comment: Move the semicolon one word to the right in that sentence and there can be no objection at all: "I rise up; me!" (Unless you think the parts of speech need to be the same.) (Although thesaurus.com does indeed have "up" listed as a synonym for the verb "rise", so that's probably fine anyways.)

Answer (score 3):

### 15 Characters

> Tell me, I say!

Whether this works depends on whether I and me are considered synonyms, both referring to myself, of course.  Clarified as allowed by OP.

### 25 Characters

> Heat drops as temps fall.

Heat and temps: refer to temperature
Drops and fall: to become lower

Comment: Nice. Defiantly better than 64!

Comment: You edited while I was typing my answer! :-) If things like 'I' and 'me' are allowed, I've got it almost as short as possible.

Comment: I don't see any reason for I and me not to be allowed...

Answer (score 1):

## 12 characters

> Be me? I am.

I know this ties the best answer, but it's also a good one. *I* and *me* are both first person singular pronouns, and *be* and *am* are both forms of the infinitive *to be*. This could be a response to the common statement "Be yourself," so it is valid sentence/pair of sentences.

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't get away with listing 'be' and 'am' as synonyms! :-(

Comment: @randal'thor Hmm. That's strange, seeing as they're synonyms just as much as *I* and *am* are. Oh well, I'll leave it up.

Comment: You mean *I* and *me*! :-) My suggestion was 'I am; be me!', which wasn't allowed since 'am' meant 'exist' and 'be' meant 'become', which weren't synonymous enough for the OP.

Comment: Oops, my bad on that. Makes sense why they aren't synonyms, but can't *be* be used to mean exist also?